# Adding javascript to a rails app page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to hide and show 2 links in my rails app

```
<a href="mailto:name@example.com", class="send_email">Invite</a>
<a href="", class="email_sent">Undo</a>
```

In my css

```
.email_sent{display: none;}
```

I added this to the bottom of the page

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
 $(function(){
  $('.send_email > a').click(function(){
   $('.send_email').hide();
   $('.email_sent').show();
  });
  $('.email_sent > a').click(function(){
   $('.send_email').show();
   $('.email_sent').hide();
  });
 });
<% end %>
```

In console I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function)
```

The page's source shows this

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
$('.send_email > a').click(function(){
$('.send_email').hide();
$('.email_sent').show();
});
$('.email_sent > a').click(function(){
$('.send_email').show();
$('.email_sent').hide();
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

How do I fix the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code should be put after the following tag.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Because the application.js file includes jQuery. your script must be loaded after the jQuery is successfully loaded. The above line of code includes application.js to your web page.

Answer (score 1):

`$` variable defined in JQuery library, so you should include it to your page before. Check that `assets/javascripts/application.js` includes this library.

FYI: your `a` tags has commas it can cause any rendering problems. Remove it.